# Primefaces BlockUi disappear after 40 mins on internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces, blockui

When I run an ajax treatment after approximately 40 min p:blockui disappear on internet explorer 9.0 and greater, but still working on mozilla firefox.

Backing bean

```
@ManagedBean @ViewScoped public class test {

HttpSession session ;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
}

public void doSomthing() {
    try {
        session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);

        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 80); // milliseconds to a second | seconds to a minute | minutes to sleep 
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Terminée", "Terminée "+session.getMaxInactiveInterval()));

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Home.xhtml

```
<h:body id="entirePage">
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid id="msg">
        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" showDetail="true" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton id="btn" value="Valider" action="#{test.doSomthing}">
        <p:ajax process="@form" update="msg" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <p:blockUI block=":entirePage" trigger="btn">
        Chargement ...
    </p:blockUI>
</h:form></h:body>
```

Comment: Blocking a ui thread for 80 minutes is bad design. And where is the IE tag? And you showserver side code while IE is client side…

Comment: What is your session expired set to? This could be involved.

Comment: @NullPtr92065 My session expired in 30 minutes, no i change session timeout to 120 minutes in web.xml, problem still persist

Comment: @Kukeltje which tag ie ? I have a treatment that takes 8 hours, that's why I simulated blockage 80 minutes for test

Comment: Even if you weva king or emperor. Still bad design. Use async for this.